# UTM to Lat/Long Conversion

Tags: php, google-maps, utm

I am extracting UTM coordinates, from this site, www.ma-investment.gov.bh/bps_ppd_en/
The coordinates are as follows on my extraction and on their website, both the top one listed, and this one https://www.ma-investment.gov.bh/website/discover_bah/Default.aspx: 
(They are the same)

Here is a screenshot from Ma-Invest/doscover_Bah: http://i57.tinypic.com/mwbea0.jpg
Here is a screenshot from /bps_pdd_en/ http://i58.tinypic.com/6yjm86.gif

Please note, even though you see an offset, on the above two, the UTM's are the same.

```
[[[466265.59,2909000.13],[466270.63,2909007.49],[466282.21,2909008.56],[466294.09,2909009.4],[466305.92,2909009.88],[466317.76,2909010.02],[466329.6,2909009.82],[466341.43,2909009.27],[466353.23,2909008.38],[466365.01,2909007.14],[466376.74,2909005.56],[466388,2909003.71],[466399.7,2909001.46],[466411.69,2908998.76],[466421.37,2908996.38],[466430.63,2908993.61],[466439.75,2908990.38],[466448.7,2908986.72],[466457.46,2908982.62],[466466.1,2908978.04],[466532.47,2908939.45],[466509,2908899.08],[466507.76,2908899.26],[466495.2,2908900],[466494.44,2908900.59],[466499.91,2908908.29],[466488.5,2908916.39],[466483.28,2908909.06],[466476.55,2908913.83],[466466.8,2908920.15],[466456.8,2908926.05],[466446.56,2908931.53],[466436.09,2908936.57],[466425.43,2908941.17],[466414.58,2908945.31],[466403.56,2908949],[466392.4,2908952.22],[466381.12,2908954.96],[466369.73,2908957.23],[466358.25,2908959.02],[466346.71,2908960.33],[466335.12,2908961.15],[466323.51,2908961.48],[466311.9,2908961.32],[466300.3,2908960.68],[466297.5,2908960.41],[466296.63,2908969.36],[466282.7,2908968],[466283.51,2908959.68],[466275.75,2908964.72],[466265.59,2909000.13]]],"envelope":[466265.59,2908899.08,466532.47,2909010.02]}}]}',map));
```

I am using gPoint.php to convert the UTM to LatLongs, with success, I then use the lat/long and plot them on a google map.

Here are my converted LatLongs

```
[ new google.maps.LatLng(26.30043717254,50.662054654926),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300503747305,50.662104951391),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300513681855,50.662220928234),new google.maps.LatLng(26.30052154664,50.662339916421),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300526159591,50.662458413154),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300527702708,50.662577018962),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300526175756,50.66269563366),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300521488206,50.662814157321),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300513729881,50.662932389321),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300502810723,50.663050430089),new google.maps.LatLng(26.30048882032,50.663167978823),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300472380852,50.66328082626),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300452339905,50.663398091879),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300428242479,50.663518274317),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300406980079,50.663615307522),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300382186313,50.663708143427),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300353235709,50.663799588799),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300320398445,50.663889342317),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300283583762,50.663977203881),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300242432132,50.664063875762),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299895545609,50.664729750755),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299530481941,50.664495685993),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299532078172,50.664483259481),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299538465576,50.664357419083),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299543775069,50.66434979036),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299613429095,50.664404386501),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299686299252,50.664289874863),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299619991897,50.664237773537),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299662904002,50.664170230891),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299719740701,50.664072394639),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299772779149,50.663972064817),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299822019574,50.66386934161),new google.maps.LatLng(26.29986728162,50.663764325721),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299908566221,50.663657417864),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299945692786,50.663548618569),new google.maps.LatLng(26.299978752076,50.663438127939),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300007564204,50.663326247034),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300032039345,50.663213176481),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300052268025,50.663099016206),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300068160418,50.662983966835),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300079717229,50.662868328911),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300086848398,50.662752202884),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300089554632,50.662635889297),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300087836401,50.662519588516),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300081784235,50.66240340047),new google.maps.LatLng(26.30007928031,50.662375358103),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300160072277,50.66236640865),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300147463919,50.662226898235),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300072359022,50.66223523024),new google.maps.LatLng(26.300117683793,50.662157361352),new google.maps.LatLng(26.30043717254,50.662054654926),  ];
```

Here is a screenshot of my result: http://i62.tinypic.com/2h68xg2.jpg

I have tried other UTM resources to convert to LatLong and the conversions are all the same[The same latlongs]. (http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/utm-latitude-longitude-d_1370.html)

The datum is :WGS 84
And I am in the N39 zone.

My question is: Why the offset from the ma-invest and bps_ppd? and why a different offset from mine?  Perhaps, when I can understand why, I can start to fix the problem.

EDIT: You can reproduce the problem by going to those sites and typing in the following parcel No: 02024813.

Comment: @Phpdna, the question is different, albeit somewhat similar. I deleted that question now. I better explained it here. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: This new question doesn't explain it better than the previous, you've omitted the most important part : ***The conversion is right, but the UTM values are wrong, and there is no way to change those UTM values.***  When you know that the values are wrong and you know the offset too apply the offset to the LatLng's, e.g. via [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Comment: @Dr.Molle. If the UTM values are wrong, why are they displaying correctly on the satellite map in the discover_bah link?

Comment: How can the same UTM values , produce two different polygons(locations)? and how can the UTM values converted to LatLong, produce yet a third different polygon(location)?

Comment: I solved my issue this way: $myHome->setUTM( ($X - 40), ($Y + 17), "39N");. 

However, that still doesn't explain why the maps display differently. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the viewport use lat longs but the projection uses mercator?